# ASIHttpRequest: requestDidFinishSelector vs. requestDidFailSelector

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios

Before I dive into ASIHttpRequest's source code:

From the documentation (http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) of ASIHttpRequest it is not completely clear to me when an ASIHttpRequest will call requestDidFinishSelector or requestDidFailSelector.

When does a request fail?

Is it correct to assume that whenever the server responds (with a corresponding HTTP status code, be it a 1xx, 2xx, 3xx, 4xx or 5xx, the request is considered successful, and therefore requestDidFinishSelector will apply?
Is 'failure' the fact that the server could not be reached?

As I type this, this seems to be the most logical answer... anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right — a request succeeds if the server responds with a HTTP status code. You can ask for this status code by using `ASIHTTPRequest`'s `responseStatusCode`.

If the request URL is invalid or your app has no access to the Internet, then your request fails. So you should implement `requestDidFailSelector` (or specify your own error handling method) and handle errors in there in any case.

Comment: because you were the fist to answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `ASIHTTPRequest` doesn't use HTTP status codes (except for redirection), so it's up to you to look out for problems (ex: 404) in your `requestDidFinishSelector` selector.

```
int statusCode = [request responseStatusCode];
NSString *statusMessage = [request responseStatusMessage];
```

`requestDidFailSelector` will be called only if there is the server can not be reached (time out, no connection, connection interrupted, ...)